# Make IntelliJ aware of a properties file

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, properties-file

Is there some way to tell IntelliJ that a particular `.properties` file will be loaded into a project's environment?  We use `@PropertySource` annotations to load properties files, and in several places load override values from a file determined by an already-configured property, like so:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:com/example/package/db.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:com/example/package/db.${db.instance}.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig {
    private @Value("${db.someProperty}") String someDBProperty;
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that within one of these indirectly referenced files, e.g. `db.test.properties`, IntelliJ doesn't know if/how the properties file is referenced, so it can't tie any of the entries to their usages.  (Bizarrely, *some* of the properties listed in these files are not greyed out to indicate 'Unused property', though even these give no results for a 'Find usages' search).  There is no issue with directly named files, e.g. `db.properties` above.

Is there some way to tell IntelliJ about these files short of creating additional dummy `@Configuration` files that reference them?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Contrary to your situation, when I use SpEL in my Java code the properties are always marked as unused.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it:

- From the project explorer, i right click in src/main/resources, I hover on "Mark Directory As..." and I click on "Resources Root"

[image]

- In the Spring configuration I just specify the name of the properties file directly.

Here an example when I am doing this in one of my projects:
https://github.com/SFRJ/springpractice/blob/master/src/main/java/part3/PropertiesLoaderConfiguration.java

By the way, if you are using multiple property sources you can also do something like this:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("a.properties"),
        @PropertySource("b.properties")
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sfrj, I'm not sure this answers the question though - I want to reference different property sources depending on a property that's already been loaded.  E.g. in the example I gave where I want to load the configuration for a specific database instance, where the DB instance to use has been configured elsewhere (in my case it is looked up at application startup time dependent on the running host).

Comment: Also the wrapper PropertySources annotation is not needed from Java 8 which supports repeatable annotations.

Comment: My problem was different (simpler).  I wanted to open a properties file using
    Properties properties = null;
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mysql.properties")

    properties.load(is);

but is was always null.  sfrj's answer solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

[image: Just look at this picture]

This can be set in project structure. Just look at this capture.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder named `res` in your project and keep the necessary property files in that folder. Go to the Project_Structures -> Modules and select the tab Resources. In your code, you can access the resource file using the path: `res/your_file_name`.

Before marking the folder as a resource folder
[image]

After marking the folder as a resource folder
[image]