# Make Intellij / SpringBoot read 2 properties files

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get the same Spring Boot application to open & run in the same  in STS 4 (Eclipse) and Intellij.  The set up is to have a properties file in main\resources with some default values and a 2nd properties file in project level config file with other properties 'simulating' an external properties file.

Currently both files are called application.properties and STS allows a right click run as a Spring Boot application with no problems.  Presumably this is a pre loaded Spring plugin ?

I can't get this to work in Intellij.  I've tried a number of configurations from named configurations to marking the config directory as a resources folder ([Make IntelliJ aware of a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365593/make-intellij-aware-of-a-properties-file)).  Every way I've found in Intellij allows an either/or strategy where either file is valid but only on its own, it won't combine the 2 files into one set of properties.

Is there a plug in or technique that will allow me to use both files (without changing the actual code to add annotations etc) ?

so

MyApp
  - config\application.properties  (extra properties not included in the jar)
  - main\resources\application.propeties (defaults)

To be clear I think I am trying to follow the correct order defined in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) ?

2.3. Application Property Files
SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:

```
A /config subdirectory of the current directory
The current directory
A classpath /config package
The classpath root
```

Comment: Is it ultimate or community version?

Comment: I'm using the Ultimate version

Comment: There are related issues on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208043, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180498